# Styling a checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I style a checkbox to appear as shown in the image below

[image]

It can be great if I can use the label element inside the checkbox. Thanks for your tips.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-checkboxes-radios and tweak a bit styles?

Comment: You will have to provide some code, this also can't be fully achieved only with CSS...
Also this looks more like a button... perhaps try using buttons it will be easier

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365028/twitter-bootstrap-button-group-control-radio-buttons-checkboxes and http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio